# In Rails 5 where should I put my javascript_include_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following tag in my application.html.erb file: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Initially it is in the `head` section, which is the default for Rails 5.2 I assume. The problem with this was that it wouldn't load the JS files in my assets/javascripts folder. I was advised to move the tag to somewhere that was after the `<%= yield %>` part but still within the `body`. This worked fine and the JS from that folder loaded ok. The problem now is that I am using the `leaflet-rails` gem and the map will not load when the `javascript_include_tag` is in the `body`... Is there anything I can do so that both these things work?

My assets/javascripts/locations.js

```
var currentLocation = document.getElementById('coordinatesStore'); 
document.querySelector('.add-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: { latitude, longitude }}) => {
    currentLocation.value = latitude + ", " + longitude;
    });
  } else {
    currentLocation.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
});
```

Comment: "The problem with this was that it wouldn't load the JS files in my assets/javascripts folder." - what do you mean by that? If the asset is referenced from `application.js`, it should be loaded.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have a file in assets/javascripts called location.js and it doesn't load unless I put this js include tag after the `yield` tag. Is there something I'm missing that would make it work and still be able to keep it in the `head` tags? My initial post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990944/rails-5-app-wont-load-js-from-assets-javascripts-folder)

Comment: Oh, but it does load. You can check by inserting a few `console.log` statements there.

Comment: Try change order of your leaflet.js file in application.js file under assets. Your location.js file might load before leaflet.js file.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, it doesn't load when it is in the head. Do I need to require it somewhere?

Comment: @Steve: no, can't be. I'll need a [mcve], I'm afraid.

Comment: @DipakGupta What do you mean my leaflet.js file? I only have a location.js file and an application.js file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you're trying to attach event handlers to elements that do not yet exist. Solution is standard: *load* the code in the head, but postpone **running** it until page loads.

```
// wrap your code in a function, so that it can be executed later
function attachLocationClickHandlers() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.add-button'),
    (button, i) => {
      // do something on click
    }
  );
}

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  attachLocationClickHandlers()
})
```

(*or something similar to that. I don't know javascript*)

Comment: Yeah, I also don't know JavaScript ;) This doesn't work. `Uncaught ReferenceError: getLocation is not defined at HTMLButtonElement`

Comment: @Steve: hm, did you not keep the definition of `getLocation`? Should be outside of `attachLocationClickHandlers` (in case it wasn't obvious).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keep the definition of getLocation". I just used your code exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: @Steve: I didn't write it, though. I rearranged parts of _your_ code from your other post. Omitting parts irrelevant for the answer.

Comment: Ah, that is no longer the code that I am using - it slightly different now. Sorry. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @Steve: well, I trust you to be able to combine the two.

Comment: I think I've fixed it by wrapping it in a function `window.onload=function(){}`. Seems to work okay. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Steve: double check that `window.onload` works as expected in your turbolinks-powered app. They tend to get in the way in situations like this (because that's what their actual job is)